# Find the duplicate rows of one column then add the corresponding rows of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to check the duplicate rows of one column and add the corresponding rows of other columns.
If the dateframe is as follows:

```
 A     B         C         D  E  F  G  
13348  xyzqr     324580    1  1  1  1
13348  grpret    325810    4  4  4  4
45832  gberthh   258729    2  1  3  4
45832  bhdrffe   025892    2  1  1  4
58712  bgrtw     984562    2  2  2  2
76493  hzrt      638495    1  1  1  2
643509 .         T648501   1  1  1  1
643509 .         R648501   1  1  1  1
```

After, adding the corresponding rows of columns (B, C, D, E, F) must check if all the columns of corresponding rows are equal. If equal give the same number to other column else '0'.
  For the above example, since there are two duplicate rows of 13348 and addition of corresponding rows give the 5 for every column of (D=5, E=5, F=5, G=5) so the output should be 5. Whereas, for the 45832 has different column (D=4, E=2, F=4, G=8) values after adding so the output should be 0.
  Remaining column should be the minimum index values of the duplicate rows.

The output should be as follows:

```
   A     B       C       D 
  13348  xyzqr   324580  5
  45832  gberthh 258729  0
  58712  bgrtw   984562  2
  76493  hzrt    638495  0
  643509 .       T648501 2
```

I am pleased to know some suggestions.

Comment: Some problem happens?

Comment: Yes, I get the output but the sum of the columns are not correct for both the duplicate and non-duplicate rows.

Comment: In my answer are 3 solutions, what do you use?

Comment: I have tried all the three, but I have the same problem. In addition, the column values are different for different methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need:

```
cols = ['D','E','F','G']
#for each group transpose df and check if all duplicates
df1 = df.groupby('A')[cols].apply(lambda x: x.T.duplicated(keep=False))
#for duplicates aggregate sum else 0
arr = np.where(df1.all(axis=1), df.groupby('A')[cols[0]].sum(), 0)
#remove unnecessary columns and add new, get first rows per column A
df = df.drop(cols, axis=1).drop_duplicates('A').assign(D=arr)
print (df)
        A        B        C  D
0   13348    xyzqr   324580  5
2   45832  gberthh   258729  0
4   58712    bgrtw   984562  2
5   76493     hzrt   638495  0
6  643509        .  T648501  2
```

Alternative solution with check each group if all values are dupes:

```
cols = ['D','E','F','G']
m = df.groupby('A')[cols].apply(lambda x: x.T.duplicated(keep=False).all())
print (m)
A
13348     True
45832    False
dtype: bool

arr = np.where(m, df.groupby('A')[cols[0]].sum(), 0)
df = df.drop(cols, axis=1).drop_duplicates('A').assign(D=arr)
print (df)
        A        B        C  D
0   13348    xyzqr   324580  5
2   45832  gberthh   258729  0
4   58712    bgrtw   984562  2
5   76493     hzrt   638495  0
6  643509        .  T648501  2
```