# How to remove duplicate rows of one column in pandas while merging the values of the remaining columns?

Tags: pandas, sum, duplicates

Please let me know if this is a duplicate, but I believe I checked most similar questions and unfortunately I haven't yet found an answer. I'm new to pandas, so sorry in advance.
After a lot of merging and groupby I have a dataframe, something like this:

```
0 A B C D E F G H I J K L
1 x 0 1 1 2 1 3 1 2 3 3 4
2 x 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 y 0 4 5 1 1 2 1 3 4 5 3
4 y 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 z 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Where B has a value, the rest of the columns doesn't, where the rest of the columns have values, B doesn't. The values are never NaN, they are always 0.0.

My Expected output would be:

```
0 A B C D E F G H I J K L
1 x 1 1 1 2 1 3 1 2 3 3 4
2 y 1 4 5 1 1 2 1 3 4 5 3
3 z 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I have followed the answers to several similar questions on here. I tried `groupby(A).agg('sum')`
Tried the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52965062/find-the-duplicate-rows-of-one-column-then-add-the-corresponding-rows-of-other-c) and several others. The result is always the same, the returned dataframe still has duplicates and the values do not sum up, Edit: or the values are completely removed.

The sample of the dataframe I have the issue with:

```
{'Higher managerial administrative and professional occupations': [0.0,
  2332.0,
  0.0,
  240.0,
  0.0],
 'Intermediate occupations': [0.0, 538.0, 0.0, 670.0, 0.0],
 'Lower managerial administrative and professional occupations': [0.0,
  2098.0,
  0.0,
  733.0,
  0.0],
 'Lower supervisory and technical occupations': [0.0, 166.0, 0.0, 321.0, 0.0],
 'MSOA11CD': ['E02000001',
  'E02000001 ',
  'E02000002',
  'E02000002 ',
  'E02000003'],
 'Never worked and long-term unemployed': [0.0, 225.0, 0.0, 503.0, 0.0],
 'Not classified': [0.0, 471.0, 0.0, 410.0, 0.0],
 'Routine occupations': [0.0, 168.0, 0.0, 659.0, 0.0],
 'Semi-routine occupations': [0.0, 290.0, 0.0, 964.0, 0.0],
 'Small employers and own account workers': [0.0, 416.0, 0.0, 478.0, 0.0],
 'number of crimes': [2125.0, 0.0, 517.0, 0.0, 1095.0]}
```

`MSOA11CD` is column `A` from above, and `number of crimes` is column `B`.
This dataframe was created by merging

```
{'Higher managerial administrative and professional occupations': [2332.0,
  240.0,
  554.0,
  288.0,
  275.0],
 'Intermediate occupations': [538.0, 670.0, 1294.0, 847.0, 894.0],
 'Lower managerial administrative and professional occupations': [2098.0,
  733.0,
  1408.0,
  875.0,
  927.0],
 'Lower supervisory and technical occupations': [166.0,
  321.0,
  516.0,
  383.0,
  516.0],
 'MSOA11CD': ['E02000001 ',
  'E02000002 ',
  'E02000003 ',
  'E02000004 ',
  'E02000005 '],
 'Never worked and long-term unemployed': [225.0, 503.0, 656.0, 407.0, 560.0],
 'Not classified': [471.0, 410.0, 635.0, 386.0, 542.0],
 'Routine occupations': [168.0, 659.0, 752.0, 603.0, 883.0],
 'Semi-routine occupations': [290.0, 964.0, 1156.0, 714.0, 1145.0],
 'Small employers and own account workers': [416.0,
  478.0,
  741.0,
  442.0,
  583.0]}
```

and

```
{'MSOA11CD': ['E02000001', 'E02000002', 'E02000003', 'E02000004', 'E02000005'], 'number of crimes': [2125, 517, 1095, 555, 914]}
```

, which was created by using `groupby` on

```
{'Falls within': ['British Transport Police',
  'City of London Police',
  'Metropolitan Police Service',
  'Metropolitan Police Service',
  'Metropolitan Police Service'],
 'MSOA11CD': ['E02000001', 'E02000001', 'E02000001', 'E02000002', 'E02000003'],
 'number of crimes': [98, 1365, 662, 517, 1095]}
```

Ideally I wanted to keep the `Falls within` column, however grouping by that resulted in losing all numerical data.
I hope this helps. Thank you.

Comment: If you use `groupby(A).agg(...)` and the result has what *appears to be* duplicates in the `A` column, it means that the values in the `A` column which appear to be the same are actually different values. They could be of different types (e.g. one is a str and the other an int) or perhaps both could be strings but they differ due to whitespace. We would have to see an [mcve] to answer this more precisely.

Comment: @unutbu Sorry, I failed to mention. The dataypes are the same (according to ```df.dtypes```). I also tried to convert the data of ```A ``` to string using ```astype(str)```. It still yields the same results.

Comment: I went into the context of the question too much @unutbu ;), you are right, `df.groupby('A').sum()` should work here

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I really appreciate it. Do you have any suggestions as to why doesn't it work if the datatypes are the same?

Comment: @Yarataran: If the values are strings, look for whitespace differences. That's the usual culprit. Find two values that should be identical (but are not getting grouped) and look at their `repr`s.

Comment: To help us reproduce the problem you are seeing, post `df.to_dict('list')` (if it is not too long). If it is too long or contains private information, edit it so it is smaller. Just make sure it still contains rows that should be combining but which do not.

Comment: @unutbu Thank you. The data is publicly available on gov.uk, so it should be fine to post. One second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of merging the dataframes stems from the spaces at end of the strings in

```
 'MSOA11CD': ['E02000001 ',
  'E02000002 ',
  'E02000003 ',
  'E02000004 ',
  'E02000005 '],
```

Notice that the other dataframes do not contain these spaces. So Pandas (correctly) treats the strings `'E02000001 '` and `'E02000001'` as distinct values.
To combine them, strip the spaces off of these strings:

```
df1['MSOA11CD'] = df1['MSOA11CD'].str.strip()
```

---

For example,

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.width = sys.maxsize
pd.options.display.max_columns = None


df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Higher managerial administrative and professional occupations': [2332.0,
      240.0,
      554.0,
      288.0,
      275.0],
     'Intermediate occupations': [538.0, 670.0, 1294.0, 847.0, 894.0],
     'Lower managerial administrative and professional occupations': [2098.0,
      733.0,
      1408.0,
      875.0,
      927.0],
     'Lower supervisory and technical occupations': [166.0,
      321.0,
      516.0,
      383.0,
      516.0],
     'MSOA11CD': ['E02000001 ',
      'E02000002 ',
      'E02000003 ',
      'E02000004 ',
      'E02000005 '],
     'Never worked and long-term unemployed': [225.0, 503.0, 656.0, 407.0, 560.0],
     'Not classified': [471.0, 410.0, 635.0, 386.0, 542.0],
     'Routine occupations': [168.0, 659.0, 752.0, 603.0, 883.0],
     'Semi-routine occupations': [290.0, 964.0, 1156.0, 714.0, 1145.0],
     'Small employers and own account workers': [416.0,
      478.0,
      741.0,
      442.0,
      583.0]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'MSOA11CD': ['E02000001', 'E02000002', 'E02000003', 'E02000004', 'E02000005'], 'number of crimes': [2125, 517, 1095, 555, 914]})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Falls within': ['British Transport Police',
      'City of London Police',
      'Metropolitan Police Service',
      'Metropolitan Police Service',
      'Metropolitan Police Service'],
     'MSOA11CD': ['E02000001', 'E02000001', 'E02000001', 'E02000002', 'E02000003'],
     'number of crimes': [98, 1365, 662, 517, 1095]})

df1['MSOA11CD'] = df1['MSOA11CD'].str.strip()
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['MSOA11CD'])
df = pd.merge(df, df3, on=['MSOA11CD'])

print(df)
```

yields

```
   Higher managerial administrative and professional occupations  Intermediate occupations  Lower managerial administrative and professional occupations  Lower supervisory and technical occupations   MSOA11CD  Never worked and long-term unemployed  Not classified  Routine occupations  Semi-routine occupations  Small employers and own account workers  number of crimes_x                 Falls within  number of crimes_y
0                                             2332.0                                 538.0                                             2098.0                                                   166.0  E02000001                                  225.0           471.0                168.0                     290.0                                    416.0                2125     British Transport Police                  98
1                                             2332.0                                 538.0                                             2098.0                                                   166.0  E02000001                                  225.0           471.0                168.0                     290.0                                    416.0                2125        City of London Police                1365
2                                             2332.0                                 538.0                                             2098.0                                                   166.0  E02000001                                  225.0           471.0                168.0                     290.0                                    416.0                2125  Metropolitan Police Service                 662
3                                              240.0                                 670.0                                              733.0                                                   321.0  E02000002                                  503.0           410.0                659.0                     964.0                                    478.0                 517  Metropolitan Police Service                 517
4                                              554.0                                1294.0                                             1408.0                                                   516.0  E02000003                                  656.0           635.0                752.0                    1156.0                                    741.0                1095  Metropolitan Police Service                1095
```

Comment: Thank you so much @unutbu!! I slipped on  a very obvious thing. I'm sorry if this was a huge waste of time for you. I guess working for 8 hours in a row doesn't help. Again, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

May be there is a space in a string value of a cell. You can try to omit the spaces using [pandas.Series.str.strip](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html). Below is a dataframe which contains a space in column A at row 0:

```
df=pd.read_csv('d:/sof/training/file5.csv', sep='\s+')
df.at[0,'A']='x '
df
```

Output:

[image]

and then i try `df.groupby('A').agg(sum, axis=0)` and the output is:

[image]

The cause of still appear duplicate values is there is a space in one value of 'x'. There is a difference between ('x') and ('x '). So make sure that there is no space in all value of A column. Below is the result after omitting all the spaces:

```
df.A=df.A.str.strip()
df=df.groupby('A').agg(sum, axis=0)
df
```

Output:

[image]

===== EDITED ====

after i see there is a space, look at this:

```
{'E02000001': Int64Index([0], dtype='int64'),
 'E02000001 ': Int64Index([1], dtype='int64'),
 'E02000002': Int64Index([2], dtype='int64'),
 'E02000002 ': Int64Index([3], dtype='int64'),
 'E02000003': Int64Index([4], dtype='int64')}
```

after using pandas.strip, the groupby will work correctly:

```
df.MSOA11CD=df.MSOA11CD.str.strip()
df.groupby('MSOA11CD').groups
```

Output:

```
{'E02000001': Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64'),
 'E02000002': Int64Index([2, 3], dtype='int64'),
 'E02000003': Int64Index([4], dtype='int64')}
```

Hope this can help you.